# Reading Complex XML Attributes

Tags: c#, xml, linq, visual-studio-2008

I have an XML file that uses a combination of attributes and tags that have data in them.

I don't have control over the structure of the XML file but I am currently switching gears to look at LINQ for parsing this and wondering if there are opinions on how best to approach this structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE call_flow SYSTEM "../../../../dtds/Callflow_1-1.dtd">
<call_flow version="1.1" serial="13903" first_element="Element1">
  <element_def name="Element1">
    <voice class="com.classname.Name">
      <static>Element1.xml</static>
    </voice>
    <exit_state name="done">
      <next_element>Element2</next_element>
    </exit_state>
  </element_def>
  <element_def name="Element2">
    <voice class="com.classname.Name2">
      <static>Element2.xml</static>
    </voice>
    <exit_state name="option1">
      <next_element>Element3</next_element>
    </exit_state>
    <exit_state name="option2">
      <next_element>Element4</next_element>
    </exit_state>
  </element_def>
  <element_def name="Element3">
    <voice class="com.classname.Name3">
      <static>Element3.xml</static>
    </voice>
    <exit_state name="done">
      <next_element>Element4</next_element>
    </exit_state>
  </element_def>
  <element_def name="Element4">
    <decision>
      <class src="com.classname.Name4"/>
    </decision>
    <exit_state name="0">
      <next_element>Element3</next_element>
    </exit_state>
    <exit_state name="1">
      <next_element>Element5</next_element>
    </exit_state>
  </element_def>
  <element_def name="Element5">
    <voice class="com.classname.Name5">
      <static>element5.xml</static>
    </voice>
  </element_def>
</call_flow>
```

I can find plenty of samples of LINQ code but am not really seeing how I'd get both the values for Next_Element and the element_def "name" property.

If someone can assist and maybe point me in the right direction, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: For element `Element4` there is two next_element nodes. You want both in the result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this:

```
var doc =  XDocument.Load("myXml.xml");
var list = doc.Descendants("element_def")
              .Select(x => new
              {
                 elDefName = x.Attribute("name").Value,
                 nextEl = x.Descendants("next_element").Select(y=> y.Value).ToList()
              });
```

It will return an `IEnumerable` of anonymous objects, where `elDefName` will be value of the name attribute of the **element_def** node and `nextEl` will contain list of possible **next_element** values.

Comment: Brilliant - I'll have a go at these and see where that puts me - Really appreciate the simplicity of what I was passing over at first look.

Comment: Being new to LINQ - is there a better way to traverse the results than a nested foreach loop?

Comment: Yes you can use nested loops. It depends what is your use case. E.g. if you want to create some objects representing the XML structure, it is ok. But if you want just some filtering it would be better to append the query I have posted above with some where conditions.

Comment: The end goal is to drop Visio shapes with attached data so I'm building an Object for each Element and pulling out child element Attributes to insert as Shape Data. Seems like I may be on the right track with this approach. Really appreciate the pointers.

Comment: Yes, then you are ok with nested loops. (Please... Mark the answer which helped you at most to resolve your issue as answered - does not matter is it is my one :-) - it will help the community)

Answer (score 3):

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(path_to_xml);
var query = from ed in xdoc.Descendants("element_def")
            select new
            {
               Name = (string)ed.Attribute("name"),
               NextElements = ed.Elements("exit_state")
                                .Select(es => (string)es.Element("next_element"))
            };
```

This query will return sequence of anonymous objects, which will have `Name` property containing `element_def` name, and names of next elements as `IEnumerable<string>`.

Comment: Quick followup - being new to LINQ I am assuming there are more efficient ways of doing something like this:

     foreach (var p in data)
     {
                 //Output the Element Name
                 Console.WriteLine("{0}", p.Name);
       //Output the Next Element
       //Account for Return elements that have no next_element
     if (p.Name.Contains("Return"))
       {
       //Do nothing because it has no NextElements
       }
     else{
     foreach (string prp in p.NextElements)
     {
     Console.WriteLine("\t\t{0}",prp.ToString());
     }
     }
     }